# Grass Gis r.viewshed how i can set max distance in meter or kilometer?

Tags: measurements, viewshed, grass-7.0

I have a problem with the `r.viewshed` max distance

wiki: "The value entered is in the same units as the cell size of the raster. "

Work: I get one geo file and where I run a viewshed with radius x(measure)

I do not know which projection and therefore which size the cells have. Perhaps one cell is 1m, 1km or 1 mile.

Is there an option for me to setup the unit in meter or kilometer beforehand?

[image: Example from a Viewshed]

Comment: What format is the source file? Can you check it in gdalinfo or similar tool?

Comment: No Sorry i can´t check it. The Map is a .tiff file and the Geo file a .shp file.

Comment: If you don't know what your input data is, the output data is indeterminate. Garbage-in, Garbage-out.

Comment: That´s why i would like to catch that. Maybe i can re-project the map?

Comment: How are you going to reproject it if you don't know what it is in now?

Comment: @BradHards Thank you for your Help. I told them that the input must be in a specific format. Thread can be closed.